# Aligning a column to the center of the page

Tags: tables

To showcase some variables, I wrote a very simple table:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rcl}
$-0.3858 * 10^{5}$ & for & $H_2O + COS \rightarrow H_2S + CO_2$  \\
$-0.6927 * 10^{5}$ & for & $2H_2O + CS_2 \rightarrow 2H_2S + CO_2$ \\
$-4.8828 * 10^{5}$ & for & $H_2 + \frac{1}{2}O_2 \rightarrow H_2O$ 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Its alignment is overall centered in my text, but I would like to overrule that and have only the central column aligned in the center of the page. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, with `tabularx`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\noindent x\hrulefill x

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{YcX}
$-0.3858 * 10^{5}$ & for & $H_2O + COS \rightarrow H_2S + CO_2$  \\
$-0.6927 * 10^{5}$ & for & $2H_2O + CS_2 \rightarrow 2H_2S + CO_2$ \\
$-4.8828 * 10^{5}$ & for & $H_2 + \frac{1}{2}O_2 \rightarrow H_2O$
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since you are using chemical formulae in your table, I suggest you to use a specialized package for that, e.g. [`chemformula`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemformula). Also, a specialized package like [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) can be used for typesetting numbers correctly.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\noindent x\hrulefill x

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{YcX}
\num{-0.3858e5} & for & \ch{H2O + COS -> H2S + CO2}\\
\num{-0.6927e5} & for & \ch{2 H2O + CS2 -> 2 H2S + CO2}\\
\num{-4.8828e5} & for & \ch{H2 + 1/2 O2 -> H2O}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option for chemical formulae is [`mhchem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\noindent x\hrulefill x

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{YcX}
\num{-0.3858e5} & for & \ce{H2O + COS -> H2S + CO2}\\
\num{-0.6927e5} & for & \ce{2 H2O + CS2 -> 2 H2S + CO2}\\
\num{-4.8828e5} & for & \ce{H2 + 1/2 O2 -> H2O}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]